# How to test content of Devise emails with email_spec gem and cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, cucumber, capybara

I am learning how to test email generation and delivery with cucumber and th email-spec gem.

I have installed the gem and generated the **email_steps.rb** file.

However the **ActionMailer::Base.deliveries** array always appears to be empty so I am not able to test the email.

My scenario looks like this:

```
Background:
    Given I visit the User Registration page

  Scenario: Happy Path - Seccessful Sign Up
    And I fill in the User Registration form correctly
    And I click Register
    Then I am redirected to the Users index page
    And I can see email confirmation notification
    And "John89@example.com" should receive an email 
    When I open the email with subject "Confirmation instructions"
    And I follow "Confirm my account" in the email
    And I am redirected to the Sign In page
    And I fill in the Sign In form correctly
    And I click Log In
    Then I am redirected to the Home page
    And I can see "Signed in successfully" notification
```

And it is failing on the

```
And "John89@example.com" should receive an email with subject "Confirmation instructions"
```

I have checked that the email is sent in the development environment with the letter opener gem but I dont know why it isnt being found in the test environment by the

```
Then /^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") should receive (an|no|\d+) emails?$/ do |address, amount|
  unread_emails_for(address).size.should == parse_email_count(amount)
end
```

step from the email-spec gem.

Is there some configuarion settings I am missing?

Comment: Is your email being sent via a background job?

Comment: I'm not sure. At the moment its just set up with the devise defaults, how can I check this? I'm not very familiar with sending emails with Rails, I'm just trying to figure it out :)

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: What would be helpful to post, should I post the Devise Initializer or the test.rb environment config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had set the

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

In the **development environment** but not in the **test environment** which meant there was an error with the email being sent in the **test environment** even though it appeared fine when doing it manually in the **development environment**.

This was the main issue, a second minor issue is that I had a capital letter in my email address which is downcased when sent. This meant when the email-spec gem looked for the email it could not find a match because they did not exactly match (the one in the deliveries array was downcased).

A great way to debug this is to set up a step definition for debugging pages in cucumber as below:

```
Then(/^show me the page$/) do
  save_and_open_page
end
```

This lets you view the current page in the browser which allowed me to see the error messages and figure out the problem.

I hope that helps if someone gets stuck on the same thing in the future